# How to use SVD inside keras layers?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, svd

My aim is to use SVD to PCA whiten the latent layer before passing it to the decoder module of an autoencoder. I have used tf.linalg.svd but it does not work since it does not contain necessary Keras parameters. So as a workaround I was trying to wrap it inside Lambda but got this error

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'.

I tried SO (E.g. [Using SVD in a custom layer in Keras/tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60137542/1100242)) and did Google search for SVD in Keras but could not find any answers. I have attached a stripped but functional code here:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import preprocessing
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense, Multiply, Subtract
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.losses import mse
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

x = np.random.randn(100, 5)
train_data = preprocessing.scale(x)

input_shape = (5, )
original_dim = train_data.shape[1]
intermediate_dim_1 = 64
intermediate_dim_2 = 16
latent_dim = 2
batch_size = 10
epochs = 15


# build encoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
layer_1 = Dense(intermediate_dim_1, activation='tanh') (inputs)
layer_2 = Dense(intermediate_dim_2, activation='tanh') (layer_1)
encoded_layer = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_layer') (layer_2)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded_layer, name='encoder')
encoder.summary()


# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
layer_1 = Dense(intermediate_dim_1, activation='tanh') (latent_inputs)
layer_2 = Dense(intermediate_dim_2, activation='tanh') (layer_1)
outputs = Dense(original_dim,activation='sigmoid') (layer_2)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()

# mean removal and pca whitening
meanX = Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0, keepdims=True))(encoded_layer)
standardized = Subtract()([encoded_layer, meanX])

sigma2 = K.dot(K.transpose(standardized), standardized)
sigma2 = Lambda(lambda x: x / batch_size)(sigma2)


s, u ,v = tf.linalg.svd(sigma2,compute_uv=True)
# s ,u ,v = Lambda(lambda x: tf.linalg.svd(x,compute_uv=True))(sigma2)

epsilon = 1e-6
# sqrt of number close to 0 leads to problem hence replace it with epsilon
si = tf.where(tf.less(s, epsilon), tf.sqrt(1 / epsilon) * tf.ones_like(s),
              tf.math.truediv(1.0, tf.sqrt(s)))
whitening_layer = u @ tf.linalg.diag(si) @ tf.transpose(v)
whitened_encoding = K.dot(standardized, whitening_layer)

# Connect models
z_decoded = decoder(standardized)
# z_decoded = decoder(whitened_encoding)

# Define losses
reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs,z_decoded)

# Instantiate autoencoder
ae = Model(inputs, z_decoded, name='autoencoder')
ae.add_loss(reconstruction_loss)

# callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
adam = optimizers.adam(learning_rate=0.002)
ae.compile(optimizer=adam)
ae.summary()
ae.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
       validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

To reproduce the error uncomment these lines and comment the one preceding it:

> 1. z_decoded = decoder(whitened_encoding)
> 2. s ,u ,v = Lambda(lambda x: tf.linalg.svd(x,compute_uv=True))(sigma2)

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to wrap the SVD inside Keras layers or an alternate implementation.
Please note that I have not included the reparameterization trick to calculate the loss to keep the code simple.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. To use SVD inside Keras, we need to use the Lambda layer. However, as Lambda returns a tensor with some additional attributes, it is best to do additional work inside the lambda function and return a tensor. Another problem with my code was the combination of encoder and decoder model which I fixed by combining the output of encoder to the input of decoder model. The working code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import preprocessing
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense, Multiply, Subtract
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.losses import mse
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

def SVD(sigma2):
    s ,u ,v = tf.linalg.svd(sigma2,compute_uv=True)
    epsilon = 1e-6
    # sqrt of number close to 0 leads to problem hence replace it with epsilon
    si = tf.where(tf.less(s, epsilon), 
                  tf.sqrt(1 / epsilon) * tf.ones_like(s), 
                  tf.math.truediv(1.0, tf.sqrt(s)))
    whitening_layer = u @ tf.linalg.diag(si) @ tf.transpose(v)
    return whitening_layer

x = np.random.randn(100, 5)
train_data = preprocessing.scale(x)

input_shape = (5, )
original_dim = train_data.shape[1]
intermediate_dim_1 = 64
intermediate_dim_2 = 16
latent_dim = 2
batch_size = 10
epochs = 15


# build encoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
layer_1 = Dense(intermediate_dim_1, activation='tanh') (inputs)
layer_2 = Dense(intermediate_dim_2, activation='tanh') (layer_1)
encoded_layer = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_layer') (layer_2)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded_layer, name='encoder')
encoder.summary()


# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
layer_1 = Dense(intermediate_dim_1, activation='tanh') (latent_inputs)
layer_2 = Dense(intermediate_dim_2, activation='tanh') (layer_1)
outputs = Dense(original_dim,activation='sigmoid') (layer_2)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()

# mean removal and pca whitening
meanX = Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0, keepdims=True))(encoded_layer)
standardized = Subtract()([encoded_layer, meanX])

sigma2 = K.dot(K.transpose(standardized), standardized)
sigma2 = Lambda(lambda x: x / batch_size)(sigma2)


# s, u ,v = tf.linalg.svd(sigma2,compute_uv=True)
whitening_layer = Lambda(SVD)(sigma2)
'''
s ,u ,v = Lambda(lambda x: tf.linalg.svd(x,compute_uv=True))(sigma2)

epsilon = 1e-6
# sqrt of number close to 0 leads to problem hence replace it with epsilon
si = tf.where(tf.less(s, epsilon), 
              tf.sqrt(1 / epsilon) * tf.ones_like(s), 
              tf.math.truediv(1.0, tf.sqrt(s)))
whitening_layer = u @ tf.linalg.diag(si) @ tf.transpose(v)
'''

print('whitening_layer shape=', np.shape(whitening_layer))
print('standardized shape=', np.shape(standardized))

whitened_encoding = K.dot(standardized, whitening_layer)

# Connect models
# z_decoded = decoder(standardized)
z_decoded = decoder(encoder(inputs))

# Define losses
reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs,z_decoded)

# Instantiate autoencoder
ae = Model(inputs, z_decoded, name='autoencoder')
ae.add_loss(reconstruction_loss)

# callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
adam = optimizers.adam(learning_rate=0.002)
ae.compile(optimizer=adam)
ae.summary()
ae.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
       validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

The output of running the code is as follows:

```
    Model: "encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
encoder_input (InputLayer)   (None, 5)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                384       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 16)                1040      
_________________________________________________________________
latent_layer (Dense)         (None, 2)                 34        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,458
Trainable params: 1,458
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "decoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 2)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 64)                192       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 16)                1040      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 85        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,317
Trainable params: 1,317
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
whitening_layer shape= (2, 2)
standardized shape= (None, 2)
/home/manish/anaconda3/envs/ica_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py:819: UserWarning: Output decoder missing from loss dictionary. We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to decoder.
  'be expecting any data to be passed to {0}.'.format(name))
Model: "autoencoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
encoder_input (InputLayer)   (None, 5)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
encoder (Model)              (None, 2)                 1458      
_________________________________________________________________
decoder (Model)              (None, 5)                 1317      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,775
Trainable params: 2,775
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 80 samples, validate on 20 samples
Epoch 1/15
2020-05-16 16:01:55.443061: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.1739 - val_loss: 1.2238
Epoch 2/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 228us/step - loss: 1.0601 - val_loss: 1.0921
Epoch 3/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 261us/step - loss: 0.9772 - val_loss: 1.0291
Epoch 4/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 223us/step - loss: 0.9385 - val_loss: 0.9875
Epoch 5/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 262us/step - loss: 0.9105 - val_loss: 0.9560
Epoch 6/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 240us/step - loss: 0.8873 - val_loss: 0.9335
Epoch 7/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 217us/step - loss: 0.8731 - val_loss: 0.9156
Epoch 8/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 253us/step - loss: 0.8564 - val_loss: 0.9061
Epoch 9/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 273us/step - loss: 0.8445 - val_loss: 0.8993
Epoch 10/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 235us/step - loss: 0.8363 - val_loss: 0.8937
Epoch 11/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 283us/step - loss: 0.8299 - val_loss: 0.8874
Epoch 12/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 254us/step - loss: 0.8227 - val_loss: 0.8832
Epoch 13/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 227us/step - loss: 0.8177 - val_loss: 0.8789
Epoch 14/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 241us/step - loss: 0.8142 - val_loss: 0.8725
Epoch 15/15
80/80 [==============================] - 0s 212us/step - loss: 0.8089 - val_loss: 0.8679
```

I hope this helps.